# Kafka spring boot application producer and unable to reflect that with Kafka Sink Connector with Avro format

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

My target is I have **spring boot application kafka producer** with **Avro** serializing property and i am excepting the message which is pushed to respective topic that should access by confluent Sink Connector and insert into mysql/Oracle database tables ,  am able to produce Avro serialize and **spring boot consumer** can Avro deserialize but my Sink connector is not working , I am not able to catch what kind of payload **sink connector** is excepting and how should be spring boot producer coded to push message such a way that sink connector can cop-up with that properties

Thanks in advance :)

This is application.yml in spring boot application

```
server: 
    port: 9000
    spring.kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: "localhost:9092"
    properties:
      schema.registry.url: "http://localhost:8081"
      specific.avro.reader: true
    producer:
      key-serializer: "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer"
      value-serializer: "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer"
    app:
      topic: event_pay2
```

**This is payload for creation of schema from spring boot application**

```
{
  "schema": {
    "type": "struct",
    "fields": [
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "userid"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "regionid"
      },
      {
        "type": "string",
        "optional": false,
        "field": "gender"
      }
    ],
    "optional": false,
    "name": "oracle.user"
  },
  "payload": {
    "userid": "User_1",
    "regionid": "Region_5",
    "gender": "FEMALE"
  }
}
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka-producer-example</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>kafka-producer-example</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>confluent</id>
        <url>http://packages.confluent.io/maven</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <confluent.version>4.0.0</confluent.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
        <version>${confluent.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.2</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
 <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>schema</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/avro/</sourceDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated/avro</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
     </pluginManagement>
</build>

</project>
```

**This is my rest call how am pushing messgae into kafka topic**

```
@PostMapping("/publish/avrodata")
public String sendMessage(@RequestBody String request) {
    sender.send(request);
    return "Published successfully";
}
```

**Finally My sink connector**

```
"name": "JDBC_Sink_EVENT_PAY",
"connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
"tasks.max": "1",
"topics": "event_pay2",
"connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/user",
"connection.user": "****",
"connection.password": "****",
"auto.create": "true",
"auto.evolve":"true",
"key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"key.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
"key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
 "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true"
```

Comment: What is the status of your connector, is it running? Do you find any errors in connect log.?

Comment: Yes .. its in running state

Comment: --------------------------Error : Value schema must be of type Struct-------------------------------------

"payload": {
    "userid": "User_1",
    "regionid": "Region_5",
    "gender": "FEMALE"
  }

Comment: Check the status of connector,  http(s)://hostname:8083/connectors/JDBC_Sink_EVENT_PAY/status

Comment: Also check the schema, http(s)://hostname:8081/subjects/event_pay2-value/versions/latest

Comment: Your schema isn't proper Avro...

Comment: I noticed an intendation error in your `application.yml` in line 3.

Answer (score 0):

Always, always debug your topic before setting up a Connector. Use `kafka-avro-console-consumer` for this. If that doesn't work, then Connect + `AvroConverter` likely won't work either (in my experience), and you can reduce the problem space.

---

If I read your code correctly, you've sent a String, and not an Avro object

```
public String sendMessage(@RequestBody String request) {
    sender.send(request);  // <--- here and ^^^^^^ here
    return "Published successfully";
}
```

Instead, you need to parse your input request into an object that was created as part of your `/src/main/resources/avro` schema data, not just forward through the incoming request as a string.

And that AVSC file might look something like

```
{
  "type": "Record",
  "namespace": "oracle.user",
  "name": "User",
  "fields": [
      { "type": "string", "name: "user_id" },
      { "type": "string", "name": "regionid" },
      { "type" "string", "name" "gender" }
   ]
}
```

Which would create a `oracle.user.User` object, making your `KafkaTemplate` need to be something like `KafkaTemplate<String, oracle.user.User> sender`

Comment: Hi, Thank you for valuable answer . I have changed code as you suggested ,Now am getting Error like ------java.io.NotSerializableException: com.kafka.kafkaproducerexample.modal.PayloadRequest-------------------  Here payload is my Modal class

Comment: And while sending message into topic through kafka connector there is issue in  connect-avro-disturbed.properties like -------------- org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Value schema must be of type Struct---------------------

``

Comment: For the second error, sounds like you are still not sending Avro, so your serializers are setup wrong somewhere. I don't know about the first error, but your Input object cannot be the same class as your generated Avro one

Comment: Note: I've never used Spring Kafka, but I do know your incoming web request must be separated from your Avro class which is being produced... Or you can just stick with JSON and let Connect just use that, but again, forget about Connect. Consume the topic on the console to debug it